# Execute pipes recursively in Abstract syntax tree

Tags: c, shell, pipe, fork, abstract-syntax-tree

I've managed to make an abstract syntax tree for my minishell, the things is 
when I tried to execute the piped commands I got stuck.

The first pipe execute and output the result to the stdout 1, while the second one grep filename either stuck or not executed at all.

I tried different approches and I got different result, yet none of theme works

I would appreciate any help.

This how my AST looks like.

```
ls -la | cat -e | grep filename
```

[image]

```
t_node      *pipe_execution(t_node *node, t_list *blt, t_line *line, int std[2])
{
    int pp[2];

    if (node)
    {
        if (node->kind == NODE_PIPE)
        {
            if (node->and_or_command->left)
            {
                pipe(pp);
                std[1] = pp[1];
                pipe_execution(node->and_or_command->left, blt, line, std);
                close(pp[1]);
            }
            if (node->and_or_command->right)
            {
                std[0] = pp[0];
                std[1] = 1;
                dprintf(2, "right std %d\n", std[1]);
                pipe_execution(node->and_or_command->right, blt, line, std);
                close(std[0]);
            }
        } else if (node->kind == NODE_SIMPLE_COMMAND)
        {
            dprintf(2, "====%s=== and stdin %d stdout %d\n", node->simple_command->head->name, std[0], std[1]);
            execute_shell(blt, line->env, node, std);
        }
    }
    return (node);
}
```

```
int        execute_shell(t_list *blt, t_list *env, t_node *node, int std[2])
{
    ...
    return (my_fork(path, env, cmds, std));
}
```

my implementation of fork process.

```
int         my_fork(char *path, t_list *env, char **cmds, int std[2])
{
    pid_t       child;
    char        **env_tab;
    int         status;

    status = 0;
    env_tab = env_to_tab(env);
    child = fork();
    if (child > 0)
        waitpid(child, &status, 0);
    else if (child == 0)
    {
        dup2(std[0], 0);
        dup2(std[1], 1);
        execve(path, cmds, env_tab);
    }
    return (status);
}
```

I hope this code make some sense.

Comment: What's wrong? What should happen and what actually happens? Can you make it into a compilable example?

Comment: the first pipe execute and output the result to the standard output 1, while the second one ```grep  filename``` either stuck or not executed at all, since I tried different approche.

Comment: Can you please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59602615/edit) that into the question?

Comment: I have done so, do you have any idea how can I execute pipe while walking the tree?

Answer (score 1):

## Pipes require concurrent execution

The problem, as far as I can tell from the code snippets you provided, is that `my_fork()` is blocking. So when you execute a process, your shell stops and wait for that process to finish, before starting the next one. If you do something simple, like:

```
/bin/echo Hello | cat
```

Then the pipe's internal buffer is big enough to store the whole input string `Hello`. Once the `/bin/echo` process finishes, you execute `cat`, which can then read the buffered data from the pipe. However, once it gets more complicated, or when the first process would send a lot more data to the pipe, its internal buffer will get full, and then it will block.

The solution is to defer calling `waitpid()` on the processes you fork until you have spawned all the processes that are part of the command line.

## Create all required pipes before starting processes

Your function `pipe_execution()` assumes that there is only a single pipe; it starts the first process with filedescriptor `0` as its input, and it starts the second process with filedescriptor `1` as its output. However, if you have multiple pipes on a single command line, like in `ls -la | cat -e | grep filename`, then the output of the `cat -e` process need to go into the second pipe, not to standard output.

You need to create the second pipe before starting the right-hand command of the first pipe. It's probably simplest to just create all the pipes before starting any of the commands. You could do this by defining multiple phases:

1. Create pipes
2. Start commands
3. Wait for all commands to finish

You can traverse the abstract syntax tree you built multiple times, each time executing one of the phases.

Comment: Thank you so much for the insight, is the way I walk the tree and call pipe correct, because I seems to me that something else is wrong.

Comment: I can't tell from the code you posted. For example, what are `pipes` and `pp`? How are they initialized?

Comment: I did some modification in the code, I hope it helps.

Comment: Your code does indeed cause the output of the right-hand side of the first pipe to go to `stdout`, because that is exactly what you told it to do with `std[1] = 1`.

Comment: I tried doing so before, but it seems either, I'm lacking the understanding of pipes, or  it will lead to the same result.
I would appreciate if you could elaborate with sample code.

Comment: Ok, I managed to convert my AST to stack, and everything works just fine.